# Curl POST request return 400

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am writing a shell script to fire few POST curl requests. I get **400** when I use the below shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
ENDPOINT="https://example.com:443/v1/API_NAME"
BODY='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -k -X POST $ENDPOINT -d $BODY
```

But when i use the body inline it works fine as show below:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -k -X POST $ENDPOINT -d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'
```

The difference in the logs as seen on terminal between both the requests is **Content-Length**. Somehow for 1st curl request the Content-Length is 1 which i believe is the reason of failure. Can someone help me why the **content length is 1** and how to resolve this?

Comment: Is it better ? `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -k "$ENDPOINT" -d "$BODY"`

Comment: Always, *always* quote your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use more quotes !

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -k "$ENDPOINT" -d "$BODY"
```

The `-X POST` is not needed when using `-d` switch

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)